# 'int' object is not callable error in class

Tags: python

In python 2.7, I am writing a class called `Zillion`, which is to act as a counter for very large integers. I believe I have it riddled out, but I keep running into `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` , which seems to mean that at some point in my code I tried to call an `int` like it was a function. Many of the examples I found on this site were simply a mathematical error where the writer omitted an operator. I can't seem to find my error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    z.increment()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
class Zillion:
    def __init__(self, digits):
        self.new = []
        self.count = 0 # for use in process and increment
        self.increment = 1 # for use in increment
        def process(self, digits):
            if digits == '':
                raise RuntimeError
            elif digits[0].isdigit() == False:
                if digits[0] == ' ' or digits[0] == ',':
                    digits = digits[1:]
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError
            elif digits[0].isdigit():
                self.new.append(int(digits[0]))
                digits = digits[1:]
                self.count += 1
            if digits != '':
                    process(self, digits)
        process(self, digits)
        if self.count == 0:
            raise RuntimeError

        self.new2 = self.new  # for use in isZero

    def toString(self):
        self.mystring =''
        self.x = 0
        while self.x < self.count:
            self.mystring = self.mystring + str(self.new[self.x])
            self.x += 1
        print(self.mystring)

    def isZero(self):
        if self.new2[0] != '0':
            return False
        elif self.new2[0] == '0':
            self.new2 = self.new2[1:]
            isZero(self)
        return True

    def increment(self):
        if self.new[self.count - self.increment] == 9:
            self.new[self.count - self.increment] = 0
            if isZero(self):
                self.count += 1
                self.new= [1] + self.new
            else:
                self.increment += 1
                increment(self)
        elif self.new[self.count - self.increment] != 9:
            self.new[self.count - self.increment] = self.new[self.count - self.increment] + 1
```

Comment: What line does the error happen? A code dump isn't useful unless you can tell us where the error happens. We're not going to try to simulate your error without all the info

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    z.increment()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I put it right at the top man

Comment: `z` must be an integer, not an instance of the `Zillion` class. Can't tell from the traceback how you defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both an instance variable and a method named `increment` that seems to be your problem with that traceback at least.

in `__init__` you define `self.increment = 1` and that masks the method with the same name

To fix, just rename one of them (and if it's the variable name, make sure you change all the places that use it--like throughout the `increment` method)

One way to see what's happening here is to use `type` to investigate.  For example:

```
>>> type(Zillion.increment)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> z = Zillion('5')
>>> type(z.incremenet)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an instance variable in `Zillion.__init__()`

```
def __init__(self, digits):
        self.new = []
        self.count = 0 
        self.increment = 1 # Here!
```

Then you defined a method with the same name 'Zillion.increment()`:

```
def increment(self):
    […]
```

So if you try to call your method like this:

```
big_number = Zillion()
big_number.increment()
```

`.ìncrement` will be the integer you have defined in `.__init__()` and not the method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a variable member `self.increment`，and it has been set to the 1 in your `__init__` function.

`z.increment` represents the variable member which set to 1.

You can rename your function from `increment` to the `_increment`(or any other names), and it will works.