# When the function is called more than once I've this error TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

My funtion withdraw() works well once but if I call it again I got a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. Please help...

```
class Accounts():
  def __init__(self, owner, balance):
      self.owner = owner
      self.balance = balance

  def deposit(self, funds):
      self.funds = funds
      self.balance = self.balance + funds
      print("{} The credit of {} was accepted. The account's new balance is now {}$" .format(self.owner, self.funds, self.balance))

  def withdraw(self, withdraw):
      self.withdraw = withdraw
      if self.withdraw < self.balance:
          self.balance = self.balance - withdraw
          print("{} The debit of {} was accepted. The account's new balance is now {}$" .format(self.owner, self.withdraw, self.balance))
      else:
          print("The withdraw's value of {}$ exceeds the balance's amount" .format(self.withdraw))


hg = Accounts("Hugo", 100)

hg.withdraw(60)
```

```
Hugo The debit of 60 was accepted. The account's new balance is now 40$

    hg.withdraw(20)

TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-5411cf9976a7> in <module>
----> 1 hg.withdraw(20)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Here: `self.withdraw = withdraw`—You set `self.withdraw` to an int. So it is not a method any more.

Comment: Here is a possible dupe: ['int' object is not callable error in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682852/int-object-is-not-callable-error-in-class)

Comment: is there any reason to set an attribute on `self` in the `withdraw` method? Replacing `self.withdraw` in the method with references to the argument would remove the issue and not affect any of your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method named `withdraw`. But you also have the line

`self.withdraw = withdraw`,

which redefines `self.withdraw` to the method's argument. So `self.withdraw` is now an integer, not a method. You can fix it by using different names, for example:

```
 def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount):
        self.withdraw_amount = withdraw_amount
        if self.withdraw_amount < self.balance:
            self.balance = self.balance - self.withdraw_amount
            print("{} The debit of {} was accepted. The account's new balance is now {}$" .format(self.owner, self.withdraw_amount, self.balance))
        else:
            print("The withdraw's value of {}$ exceeds the balance's amount" .format(self.withdraw_amount))
```

Comment: I've just did that and worked fine. I have learned a lesson this time that is good practice in Python using different names for methods and methods arguments. Many thanks perigon

Comment: You're welcome! You can hit the green checkmark to accept an answer that solved your problem.